# При попытке собрать образ через maven выдаёт ошибку. использую graalvm

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

Пытаюсь собрать проект по [этому](https://www.graalvm.org/dev/reference-manual/native-image/guides/use-native-image-maven-plugin/) гайду
Но выдаёт следующую ошибку:

> [ERROR] Command execution failed. org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Process exited with an error: 1 (Exit value: 1) at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.executeInternal (DefaultExecutor.java:404) at org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor.execute (DefaultExecutor.java:166) at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:1000) at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.executeCommandLine (ExecMojo.java:947) at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecMojo.execute (ExecMojo.java:471) at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56) at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:294) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192) at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293) at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196) at jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke (DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:578) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406) at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)

мой pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>native</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>java-agent</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>java</executable>
                                    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                                    <arguments>
                                        <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                        <classpath/>
                                        <argument>${mainClass}</argument>
                                    </arguments>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <executable>${project.build.directory}/${imageName}</executable>
                                    <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}</workingDirectory>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.graalvm.buildtools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>native-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${native.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                        <extensions>true</extensions>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>build-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>test-native</id>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>test</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>test</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <fallback>false</fallback>
                            <buildArgs>
                                <arg>-H:DashboardDump=fortune -H:+DashboardAll</arg>
                            </buildArgs>
                            <agent>
                                <enabled>true</enabled>
                                <options>
                                    <option>experimental-class-loader-support</option>
                                </options>
                            </agent>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>adianov.sergei</groupId>
    <artifactId>COVID-Risk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>COVID-Risk</name>

    <properties>
        <native.maven.plugin.version>0.9.18</native.maven.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.specification.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.specification.version}</maven.compiler.target>
        <imageName>COVID Risking</imageName>
        <mainClass>MainApp</mainClass>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/exec-maven-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>19-ea+7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.controlsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>controlsfx</artifactId>
            <version>11.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.dlsc.formsfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>formsfx-core</artifactId>
            <version>11.5.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <to>
                        <image>docker.io/heartofglass404/COVID_Risking</image>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>adianov.sergei.covidrisk/adianov.sergei.covidrisk.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Вы используете код примера с GitHub или свой? GraalVM у Вас конечно-же уже установлен и в JAVA_HOME путь к нему прописан...

Comment: код у меня свой. Да, graalvm установлен и путь прописан

Comment: Попробуйте запустить код/проект из официального примера. Далее, шаг за шагом, Вы сможете исключать возможные причины. В худшем случае можно сравнить проекты между собой.